# Grunt: Watch file changes and compile parent directory

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm working on a project using grunt, I haven't worked with grunt before and currently this is setup as to watch files and when a file has been changed recompile all the files (multiple subdirectories containing hundreds of files) using handlebars into html which is quite slow. I want to improve this to a faster process by only compiling what is needed.

Watching the files with grunt newer doesn't really work because there are dependencies within the directory and thus only recompiling the changed files will not result in a valid page.

I would basically need to recompile the whole parent directory of the file that has changed, but I'm not quite sure on how I would configure something like that.

Any hints where I should look at?

The assemble itself is configured like this:

```
 var _ = require('lodash');
 var path = require('path');
 // expand the data files and loop over each filepath
 var pages = _.flatten(_.map(grunt.file.expand('./src/**/*.json'), function(filepath) {
    // read in the data file
    var data = grunt.file.readJSON(filepath);
    var dest=path.dirname(filepath)+ '/' +path.basename(filepath, path.extname(filepath));
    dest=dest.replace("src/","");
    var hbs;
    if (data.hbs){
        hbs=grunt.file.read(path.dirname(filepath)+ '/' + data.hbs)
    }

    // create a 'page' object to add to the 'pages' collection
    return {
    // the filename will determine how the page is named later
    filename: dest,
    // the data from the json file
    data: data,
    // add the recipe template as the page content
    content:hbs 
    };
 }));

return {
    options: {
        /*postprocess: require('pretty'),*/
        marked: {sanitize: false},
        data: '<%= options.src %>/**/*.json',
        helpers: '<%= options.src %>/helpers/helper-*.js',
        layoutdir: '<%= options.src %>/templates',
        partials: ['<%= options.src %>/components/**/*.hbs']
    },
    build: {
        options: {
            layout: 'base.hbs',
            assets: '<%= options.build %>',
            pages: pages
        },
        files: [
            {
                cwd: '<%= options.src %>', 
                dest: '<%= options.build %>',
                src: '!*'
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

So every time this loads all the pages get scanned down like /src/sites/abc/xyz/foo.json and get compiled, but I only want to have changed files. Watch does detect changed files, but all the files get compiled again and I'm not sure how I could get the changed files that watch has recognized in the config to only process part of the files.

Comment: Could you show us the config related to question?

Comment: Sure, I've added what I understand to be the essential code for the assemble process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is already there in watch.

Check the [Using the watch event](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#user-content-using-the-watch-event) in grunt doc.

Copying down the content here to satisfy the `SO MODS/GODS`.

This task will emit a watch event when watched files are modified. This is useful if you would like a simple notification when files are edited or if you're using this task in tandem with another task. Here is a simple example using the watch event:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    scripts: {
      files: ['lib/*.js'],
    },
  },
});
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  grunt.log.writeln(target + ': ' + filepath + ' has ' + action);
});
```

The watch event is not intended for replacing the standard Grunt API for configuring and running tasks. If you're trying to run tasks from within the watch event you're more than likely doing it wrong. Please read configuring tasks.

Compiling Files As Needed

A very common request is to only compile files as needed. Here is an example that will only lint changed files with the jshint task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    scripts: {
      files: ['lib/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint'],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
      },
    },
  },
  jshint: {
    all: {
      src: ['lib/*.js'],
    },
  },
});

// on watch events configure jshint:all to only run on changed file
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  grunt.config('jshint.all.src', filepath);
});
```

If you need to dynamically modify your config, the spawn option must be disabled to keep the watch running under the same context.

If you save multiple files simultaneously you may opt for a more robust method:

```
var changedFiles = Object.create(null);
var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
  grunt.config('jshint.all.src', Object.keys(changedFiles));
  changedFiles = Object.create(null);
}, 200);
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  changedFiles[filepath] = action;
  onChange();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, using the event hook I could scan for the directories files and then put those into the assemble process. The `spawn: false` is quite important for this solution - I didn't care to include that which made the assemble process to spawn in a new thread where the options reverted to default.